# insert null integer into Google bigquery

Tags: insert, google-bigquery

I am trying to import records to bigquery table which exported from mysql.

The data is exported as csv but has to be separated by tabs '\t' as some fields store json file as string, so the normal separator won't work.

From mysql, some fields (`integer`, `float`) are `null` but are shown as \N when exported.

For example:

> 123   456 '2.2.0.159' 'monday'    'London'    'GB'    \N  1026    0

I am trying to replace \N as `null`(also tried `NULL`, `Null`, all of them are not working) and upload to big query  but I'm getting the following error:

> Line:1 / Field:7, Value cannot be converted to expected type

What is the syntax in bigquery to allow me to import a value as null?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try an empty field -- e.g. for csv, just `,,`. or for tsv, `\t\t`. We should likely add support for \N if that is the syntax used by MySql.

Comment: please, it is the mysql syntax
[link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/null-values.html)

Comment: This feature is being tracked on the BigQuery issue tracker. To help prioritize this feature, please "star" the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=null&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=206) .

Answer (score 0):

I can see that this was not handled yet as NULL or \N are caught as errors but the GBQ importer.