# Loading CSV with NULLs columns using bq load

Tags: mysql, csv, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a CSV file(TSV actually) generated in mysql(using outfile) into Bigquery using bq tool. This table has following schema:

[image]

Here is the sample data file:

```
"6.02"  "0000"  "101"   \N  "Md Fiesta Chicken|1|6.69|M|300212|100|100^M Sourdough|1|0|M|51301|112|112" "6.5"   \N  "V03"   "24270310376"   "10/17/2014 3:34 PM"    "6.02"  "30103" "452"   "302998"    "2014-12-08 10:57:15"   \N
```

And this is how I try to upload it using bq CLI tool:

```
$ bq load -F '\t' --quote '"' --allow_jagged_rows receipt_archive.receipts /tmp/rec.csv
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
'circular-gist-812:bqjob_r8d0bbc3192b065_0000014ab097c63c_1': Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.
Failure details:
- File: 0 / Line:1 / Field:16: Could not parse '\N' as a timestamp.
Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]
```

I think the issue is that `updated_at` column is `NULL` & hence skipped. so any idea how can I tell it to consider null/empty columns?

Comment: It's not "skipped"; it's rejected.

Comment: @Strawberry: Rep does not indicate programming expertise!

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13050296/560648 (probably enough to call it a dupe); this looks like a format discrepancy between the export and input tools (`\N` is not "standard" CSV)

Comment: @Strawberry What you mean? "it's amazingly unlikely that payable would be a FLOAT" why can't be float? Its the amount payable. if not float, what datatype would it be?

Comment: decimal. People can be pretty sticky about those piddly little fractions!

Comment: Ideally yes, but what if there is no decimal data type? float seems a good option.

Answer (score 1):

CuriousMind - This isn't an answer. Just an example of the problem of using floats instead of decimals...

```
CREATE TABLE fd (f FLOAT(5,2),d DECIMAL(5,2));

INSERT INTO fd VALUES (100.30,100.30),(100.70,100.70;

SELECT * FROM fd;
+--------+--------+
| f      | d      |
+--------+--------+
| 100.30 | 100.30 |
| 100.70 | 100.70 |
+--------+--------+

SELECT f/3+f/3+f/3,d/3+d/3+d/3 FROM fd;
+-------------+-------------+
| f/3+f/3+f/3 | d/3+d/3+d/3 |
+-------------+-------------+
|  100.300003 |  100.300000 |
|  100.699997 |  100.700000 |
+-------------+-------------+

SELECT (f/3)*3,(d/3)*3 FROM fd;
+------------+------------+
| (f/3)*3    | (d/3)*3    |
+------------+------------+
| 100.300003 | 100.300000 |
| 100.699997 | 100.700000 |
+------------+------------+
```

But why is this a problem, I hear you ask?

Well, consider the following...

```
SELECT * FROM fd WHERE f <= 100.699997;
+--------+--------+
| f      | d      |
+--------+--------+
| 100.30 | 100.30 |
| 100.70 | 100.70 |
+--------+--------+
```

...now surely that's not what would be expected when dealing with money?

Comment: Right except big query doesn't support decimals. As you can see from [this list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#datatypes) there is no decimal datatype. Only integers & floats. Makes sense?

Comment: I hadn't appreciated that [gulps]. But does it matter? What happens when bq encounters mysql's decimal data type?

Comment: "What happens when bq encounters mysql's decimal data type" - It shouldn't be a problem as `6.7` is `6.7` when stored as float or decimal.  we only have to be careful when doing arithmetic on them.

Answer (score 1):

To specify "null" in a CSV file, elide all data for the field. (It looks like you are using an unspecified escape syntax "\N".)

For example:

```
$ echo 2, > rows.csv
$ bq load tmp.test rows.csv a:integer,b:integer
$ bq head tmp.test
+---+------+
| a |  b   |
+---+------+
| 2 | NULL |
+---+------+
```